# Canvas not displaying on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, canvas

HTML5 canvas (only using the drawImage function) is not showing up on mobile devices, but is on my laptop.

You can see here : [mmhudson.com/index.html](http://mmhudson.com/index.html) (reload once)

I get no errors or anything, but it doesn't display in chrome on iOS or the default browser on android..

EDIT:

This problem only occurs when the following meta tag is included in the document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `init()` function is called by `imgLoad()`, but you're loading images only when the window width is greater than or equal to 480px:

```
        window.onload = function(){
            s.dL = true;
            s.width = window.innerWidth;
            s.height = window.innerHeight;


            if(s.width < 320){
                //too small
            }
            else if(s.width >= 320 && s.width < 480){
                s.scWidth = 296;

            }
            else{
                s.scWidth = 456;
                b_border.src = "res/480/b_border.png";
                r_border.src = "res/480/r_border.png";
                l_border.src = "res/480/l_border.png";
                t_border.src = "res/480/t_border.png";
                br_corner.src = "res/480/br_corner.png";
                tr_corner.src = "res/480/tr_corner.png";
                bl_corner.src = "res/480/bl_corner.png";
                tl_corner.src = "res/480/tl_corner.png";
                h_wall.src = "res/480/h_wall.png";
                v_wall.src = "res/480/v_wall.png";
                box.src = "res/480/box.png";
                crosshair.src = "res/480/crosshair.png";
                player1.src = "res/480/player1.png";
                player2.src = "res/480/player2.png";
            }
        }
```

When you omit the meta viewport tag, the browser assumes a page / window width of 980px, and so your code runs normally.

When you include a meta viewport tag with `width=device-width`, the browser sets the page / window width to the width of the screen (e.g. 320px on iPhone), and so `imgLoad()` and `init()` is never called.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to draw the images before they have loaded. I'm not sure why the mobile browsers would fail more often, possibly they are slower to load them all in?

In fact, when i open your page on my desktop, sometimes the canvas does not draw, but if I open the console and enter `draw()` it appears (because by then the images have loaded).

If you were dealing with just a single image, the simplified code would be:

```
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function(){ 

    // drawing code goes here

}

img.src = 'myfile.png';
```

But because of the large number of images you have here, I would look into a resource loading library of some sort.

Comment: I will do that eventually. That is what I am asking. I know the images have to download before they can be displayed... The images do get downloaded on the phone though, and then aren't displayed. See edit

Comment: If you alert `s.width` what do you get? The viewport tag could be affecting the canvas width. Also try alerting `document.getElementById("canvasCont").style.width` just before draw to make sure it has a width.

Comment: Is the canvas displaying at all? If you do something to the canvas which doesn't rely on the images, such as filling it with a solid color, does that show up?

Comment: Yes. The canvas is there and js works and correctly sizes the canvas. There are just no images displayed when that meta tag is present.